# Blazor works but shows Errors, in Counter page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

My blazor page is completly new I added nothing to it and it's default template is showing some errors but working fine, I don't understand can somebody explain them?

https://imgur.com/gallery/wXNctuc

Comment: The compiler is sad and confused...Just close the counter window and re-open it.

Comment: No it's the same problem :/

Comment: Is that the JetBrains IDE (if so, does it need an update or extension?)? Does it build the application and runs int he browser?

Comment: No it was solved i just deleted the solution and recreated a new one about 10 times and it solved :/

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using Visual Studio for Mac.
Maybe you can have a look at this page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/blazor?view=vsmac-2019

Also make sure that you're using Visual Studio for Mac 8.6+ for Blazor (Client-/Server-Side)

If this will not solve please show us the compile-errors.

Comment: Yeah I did as was shown finally was solved after deleting and creating the same way for about 10 times now I have other problems  I will add them

Comment: I have the same problem once again :/

Comment: give me more details pls than i can help you